# asp.net :how to use eventargs for parameter passing on button onclick?

Tags: asp.net, parameters, button, eventargs

i have seen some code in which people pass parameter through commandParameter Property of web control.then what is use of eventargs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone please explain to me in the most layman terms how to use EventArgs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778952/can-someone-please-explain-to-me-in-the-most-layman-terms-how-to-use-eventargs)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This can be useful if you have the same EventHandler method for different buttons. Example, say your markup looks like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" CommandArgument="MyVal1"
   CommandName="ThisBtnClick" OnClick="MyBtnHandler" />
<asp:Button ID="button2" runat="server" CommandArgument="MyVal2"
   CommandName="ThatBtnClick" OnClick="MyBtnHandler" />
```

You can have the same event handler for both buttons and differentiate based on the CommandName:

```
protected void MyBtnHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button btn = (Button)sender;
          switch (btn.CommandName)
          {
                case "ThisBtnClick":
                    DoWhatever(btn.CommandArgument.ToString());
                    break;
                case "ThatBtnClick":
                    DoSomethingElse(btn.CommandArgument.ToString());
                    break;
           }
}
```

**Source:** [aspnet-passing-parameters-in-button-click-handler](http://www.devchix.com/2007/08/10/aspnet-passing-parameters-in-button-click-handler/)

Comment: I guess I don't understand why a regular function call wouldn't work. I can call a function with empty arguements, I can call a function and pass a variable to it, but I can't say "myfunction(\"option1\")"

Answer (score 6):

Various Button type controls in .NET have an `OnCommand` event as well as an `OnClick` event. When using the `OnCommand` event you have additional parameters you can apply to the Button such as `CommandName` and `CommandArgument`. These can then be accessed in the `CommandEventArgs`.

It is useful in places where you want to assign the same method to multiple buttons and use the `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` parameters to indicate what functionality clicking that button will produce.

Answer (score 5):

The `EventArgs` class is a base class. Other web methods use other Event args.

e.g. a LinkButton has an OnClick event with a default EventArgs parameter, but it also has an OnCommand event that takes a `CommandEventArgs : EventArgs` parameter which has some extra information (namely CommandName & CommandArgument).

The event args base class is just there as a place holder so that all the EventHandlers conform to a similar signature.