# Can someone please explain to me in the most layman terms how to use EventArgs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, eventargs

I know they have something to do with delegates.  I've tried but I still don't comprehend how to use those either.  I know a little about event handlers but what I really want to know is how I can use plain old eventargs that are part of most methods.  example below

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
myText.Value = "Hello World!";
}
```

Thanks for your time & consideration, I am just trying to be the best coder I can be.

Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EventArgs classes are used as data carriers when raising events. They typically contain information that is related to the event being raised.

Many events use the EventArgs class, which contains no particular information. This class also serves as the base class for all other EventArgs classes. One example of a more specific EventArgs class is the [`TreeNodeEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenodeeventargs.aspx) class, that is used by a number of events, and that contains information about which TreeNode that the event is related to.

In some cases, EventArgs classes can be designed so that they allow event handlers to communicate data back to the source that raised the event, an example of that is the [`CancelEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.aspx) class.

Answer (score 3):

The base `EventArgs` class is an emtpy class that you can't use directly.

However, there are many derived EventArgs classes that provide data about an event.

For example, the `KeyPress` event gives a [`KeyPressEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.aspx) which tells you which key was pressed.

If you get an event handler where the `e` parameter is an inherited `EventArgs`, you can use the properties on the inherited `EventArgs` object to find out more about the event.

Comment: I agree with everything you said except not being able to use `EventArgs` directly - what prevents someone from using `EventArgs` directly?

Comment: There is nothing you can do with it.

Comment: @SLaks - I still don't completely understand - one of the main usages of the type is its `Empty` property which is very useful when you need to raise a method without any `EventArgs`.

Comment: I meant that there is nothing an event handler can do with an `EventArgs` instance.  (Except cast it)

Answer (score 1):

Plain old `EventArgs` are not really that useful, however types that *derive* from `EventArgs` are much more useful since you can define other members to carry strongly-typed data.

A good example of this is the [`GridViewEditEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewediteventargs.aspx) that are passed by a `GridView` inherit from `EventArgs` but extend it to provide `NewEditIndex` and `Cancel` properties.